# strongest chess engine

Tags: engines

Can somebody tell me where can i find an updated list of the strongest chess engines. I want to find out a comparison (ordered list of engines)

Information on wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_engine is very outdated.
Typing strongest chess engine in google either gives links for 2011 year pages or to the sites of an engine with ads that it is the best. Sometimes I see tests done by random people on the laptop with a lot of fuss.

So it looks strange to me that I can not encounter official results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_engine#Ratings) seems pretty up-to-date to me. I will retype a couple of the links from it.

- The [CCRL 40/40](http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/4040/) list runs programs at the time control of 40 moves in 40 minutes.
- The [CEGT 40/120](http://www.husvankempen.de/nunn//40120new/40_120_ratinglist/40_120_AllVersion/rangliste.html) list runs programs at the time control of 40 moves in 120 minutes.

There are four other links in the Rating List table from that Wikipedia link that may be worth exploring, though they seem to run at shorter time controls or with a smaller list of engines.

Pretty much every rating list that includes Houdini has it in the top spot.

Answer (score 5):

There are several online chess engine competitions running online. The winners of those, certainly the top five, are likely to statistically be among the stronger engines.

One such competition is: http://www.tcec-chess.net/live.php

You can DDG for others.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://stockfishchess.org/download/) you can get Stockfish, the #2 engine in the world (second only to Houdini 3), rated a cool 3100.

Comment: Stockfish 7 is now the #1 Engine by rating, as of September 2016.