# What is the strongest chess engine for blitz time controls?

Tags: engines, blitz

There are all kinds of lists of the strongest chess engines at standard time controls. [Here's](http://computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/404/) one I picked more or less at random. But does anyone track which engines are strongest at faster time controls, say, game in 5 minutes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [strongest chess engine](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/strongest-chess-engine)

Comment: The list you link to contains engine comparisons using 40 moves in 4 minutes - does that not answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FranS points out, the [CCRL 40/4 list I linked to](http://computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/404/) fits the bill pretty well. I was digging around on a lot of sites and must have thought that this one was showing results for 40 moves in 4 hours. I'm leaving the question up rather than deleting it in case someone comes along with the same question later.

Also, by following some links on [the question that @Salvador Dali linked to](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/strongest-chess-engine) I learned that there was an event called [The World Computer Speed Chess Championship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Computer_Speed_Chess_Championship) that seems to have died after 2011.

Comment: Consider accepting your answer by clicking on a checkmark on the left side. Best regards.

Comment: Will do, but it seems I have to wait a day before I can accept my own answer.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Best regards.